# Where do I store user's files?

Tags: architecture, windows-server-2008, storage

I have a ASP.NET system that creates files (> 20 MB) for users and stores it currently on a folder in the web server.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Amazon's Simple Storage platform:

http://aws.amazon.com/s3/

You could store your files in a SQL database as blob fields.

Bandwidth of 300 GB signifies the amount of data they will let you transfer per month before  they will cut your site off or start charging you per GB (depending on who the provider is)

Comment: Users downloading files can be considered as "transfer"? Does it also include HTTP traffic?

Comment: Yes, any file the web server serves up to a remote client is included in the bandwidth count. Some providers include FTP transfers in the count as well.

Comment: Users downloading files will be considered transfer. All HTTP traffic is normally considered transfer. Some hosts ignore upload from the quota, you'll need to check your terms.

Comment: I agree with the amazon part of this answer. Using a cloud service could solve your problems. You could also get a cheap hosting plan that offers unlimited storage and bandwidth and link the two together.

Answer (score 0):

Get a cheap hosting plan with another provider that offers unlimited bandwidth and file storage and create a secure service that accepts file requests. Then every time you want to save a file just make a request to your service.

Comment: Can you recommend a cheap hosting plan? I assume you are saying have 2 different hosting plans - one for the web server and another one to simply store the files?